# How to increase call log archive to longer than 30 days?

Tags: calls, phone-app, call-history

Is it possible to increase the time length covered by call history records? I think it's currently fixed to 1 month, older entries will be deleted by the log rotator. Is this hard-coded?

I know there are some utilities exist to backup / archive call logs, however archiving takes the functionality away from the dialer history. So I take archiving methods under another topic, for an even longer or a permanent call history.

Info: Using Samsung Galaxy S, not rooted, I can root if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested on applications to backup call logs:

- [Call Logs Backup & Restore](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.riteshsahu.CallLogBackupRestore)

Comment: thank you lie, I'm aware about this kind of software, however I consider archiving as a second step. I've updated the question with a note.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a phone call log using Google Calendar using the [CallTrack](https://market.android.com/details?id=app.calltrack) app which has the option to send it to your Google Calendar.

Comment: thank you dghughes, I'm aware about the application you mentioned, however I consider archiving as a second step. I've updated the question with a note. what I need is to increase the coverage so I can see the records in people histories / central call history.